# .htaccess redirection based on number of slashes(/) in url

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

This is my first htaccess file.

this is what i have written

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule \.(css|js|png|jpg|gif|otf|eot|svg|ttf|woff|jpeg)$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ maincategory/index.php?main=$1&sub=$2 [L,QSA,NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ subcategory/index.php?main=$1&sub=$2&cat=$3 [L,QSA,NC]
```

The problem what I am facing is both are pointing to maincategory.
How can I redirect based on number of "/" in the URL?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by `both are pointing to maincategory`?

Answer (score 0):

Rearrange the rules and try it this way. Let me know if that works for you.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule \.(css|js|png|jpg|gif|otf|eot|svg|ttf|woff|jpeg)$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ subcategory/index.php?main=$1&sub=$2&cat=$3 [L,QSA,NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ maincategory/index.php?main=$1&sub=$2 [L,QSA,NC]
```